# Otra opción para evitar condicionales anidados

Tags: javascript, function

espero que se encuentren muy bien, quería preguntarles que otra opción tendría para reducir esta "mala practica", de condicionales anidados, tengo la siguiente función

```
var Internet = "1";
var Tv = "1";
var Linea = "1";
var DTv = "1";

function probabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv) {

Internet = parseInt(Internet);
Tv = parseInt(Tv);
Linea = parseInt(Linea); 
DTv= parseInt(DirecTV);

if(Linea && Tv && Internet == 1){
    return 1
}
else if(Linea && Tv && Internet && DTv == 1){
    return 2
}
else if(Linea && Tv && Internet == 1){
    return 3
}
else if(Linea && Tv && DTv == 1){
    return 4
}
else if(Linea && Internet == 1){
    return 5
}
else if(Linea && Internet && DTv == 1){
    return 6
}
else if(Tv && Internet == 1){
    return 7
}
else if(Tv && Internet && DTv == 1){
    return 8
}
else if(Linea == 1){
    return 9
}
else if(Linea && DTv == 1){
    return 10
}
else if(Tv == 1){
    return 11
}
else if(Tv && DTv == 1){
    return 12
}
else if(Internet == 1){
    return 13
}
else if(Internet && DTv == 1){
    return 14
}
else if(DTv == 1){
    return 15
}
else {
    return 0
}
}
```

Si utilizo un `switch` tampoco pienso que quedaría bien, y quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar pensando en algo más practico y que quede mucho mejor. Aclaro que las variables que estoy pasando cómo argumentos a la función `probabilidades();` pueden venir en `1` o en `0` entonces dependiendo de eso aplico los condicionales. Agradecería cualquier ayuda

Comment: podrías quitar la comparativa de "== 1", pues  el número 0 es considerado en false, así que si sólo dejaras los && también funciona

Comment: además de que, con condicionales así de grandes, lo ideal es usar un switch, pues ahorras en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: Si haces `if` y `return`, no tiene sentido usar `else if` ni `else`. PD: la condición para obtener 1 es igual que la del 3.

Comment: que significa que sean iguales a `"1"`, en algún momento podrían valer `"2"` o `"8888"` o `"0"`? que otras posibilidades tienes? que posibles valores tienen esos campos? Estoy suponiendo que es un sistema para una empresa de telecomunicaciones y dependiendo de los servicios que alguien contrate, retornas el tipo de servicio o algo asi? (Porfa aclaralo) porque si es así, en vez de un `"1"` o un `"0"` podrías mejor usar un `true` o un `false`

Comment: Porque te podría sugerir una respuesta muy corta dependiendo de lo que respondas

Comment: Ya vi que tenias en la pregunta que solo podian valer 0 o 1, te acabo de dejar una respuesta muy corta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que quede mucho mejor pero puedes definir una función que devuelve un objecto con las diferentes combinaciones. Algo como esto:

```js
const generarProbabilidades = (internet, tv, linea, dtv) => ({
  0: !linea && !tv && !internet && !dtv,
  1: linea && tv && internet && !dtv,
  2: linea && tv && internet && dtv,
  3: linea && tv && internet && !dtv,
  4: linea && tv && !internet && dtv,
  5: linea && !tv && !internet && dtv,
  6: linea && !tv && internet && dtv,
  7: !linea && tv && internet && !dtv,
  8: !linea && tv && internet && dtv,
  9: linea && !tv && !internet && !dtv,
  10: linea && !tv && !internet && dtv,
  11: !linea && tv && !internet && !dtv,
  12: !linea && tv && !internet && dtv,
  13: !linea && tv && internet && !dtv,
  14: !linea && !tv && internet && dtv,
  15: !linea && !tv && !internet && dtv,
});

const probabilidad = (internet, tv, linea, dtv) => {
  const probabilidades = generarProbabilidades(+internet, +tv, +linea, +dtv);
  
  return Object.keys(probabilidades).filter((key) => probabilidades[key])[0] || 0;
};

console.log(probabilidad('1','1','1','1'));
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por está gran respuesta, me ah funcionado tal cual, gracias <3

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta mas corta que se me ocurre (pero quizás un poco mas complicada de entender) sería esta:

```
    function probabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv) {
      var valorConjunto = Internet<<3 | Tv<<2 | Linea<<1 | DTv;
      const respuestasSegunValorConjunto = [0,15,9,10,11,12,null,4,13,14,5,6,7,8,1,2];
      return respuestasSegunValorConjunto[valorConjunto];
    }
```

Pongamosla a prueba:

```js
function probabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv) {
  var valorConjunto = Internet<<3 | Tv<<2 | Linea<<1 | DTv;
  const respuestasSegunValorConjunto = [0,15,9,10,11,12,null,4,13,14,5,6,7,8,1,2];
  return respuestasSegunValorConjunto[valorConjunto];
}

//Probamos algunas (Pongo el ejemplo de tus condicionales para validar que devuelva lo correcto)

//else if(Linea && Tv && Internet && DTv == 1){
//    return 2
//}
console.log(probabilidades(1,1,1,1));


//else if(Linea && Internet && DTv == 1){
//    return 6
//}
console.log(probabilidades(1,0,1,1));


//else if(Internet && DTv == 1){
//    return 14
//}
console.log(probabilidades(1,0,0,1));
```

***Explicación:***

Lo que estamos haciendo es que como tienes 4 valores que pueden valer 0 o 1, es un buen candidato para manejarse en conjunto como un unico valor.
Como sabes los numeros se pueden representar en binario, por ejemplo:

```
7 = 0111
15 = 1111
5 = 0101
```

Hacemos exactamente lo mismo con tus 4 variables

```
var valorConjunto = Internet<<3 | Tv<<2 | Linea<<1 | DTv;
```

Aqui logramos que  Internet sea el bit de la izquierda, Tv el bit que le sigue, Linea el bit que le sigue y DTv el bit que le sigue.

Todos esos juntos darán un único numero segun su combinación (De 0 a 15)

Luego usamos esa posición en un array predefinido que nos dice que debería devolver esa combinacion.

Entonces si tenemos `Internet=1`, `Tv=1`, `Linea=1` y `DTv=1` segun tus condicionales debería devolver 2.
Al convertir esos 4 valores en un unico numero con bits nos da el valor 15. Lo que significa que en la posicion 15 del array ponemos el 2.

```
const respuestasSegunValorConjunto = [0,15,9,10,11,12,null,4,13,14,5,6,7,8,1,2];
                                                                             ^
```

(Y así sucesivamente con los demás llené el array).

Ahora lo único que basta es que la función devuelva lo que todos los datos en conjunto deberían devolver.

`return respuestasSegunValorConjunto[valorConjunto];`

Nota: Existe un valor null en el array, pero es el que corresponde en tu ejemplo al IF que está repetido. Cuando lo corrijas sabrás que valor poner ahí.

Saludos.

Comment: Impresionante jeje entendido al 100, muchas gracias por tú apoyo, me sirvió mucho

Answer (score 1):

Tal como ya te han dicho en los comentarios, el switch con un valor booleano es ideal para este tipo de estructuras (al menos desde mi punto de vista).

Aún así, la lógica que empleas en los **if** no es correcta, pues muchos casos nunca se cumpliran.

Así es como quedaría con switch con tu actual orden de condicionales:

```js
var Internet = "1";
var Tv = "1";
var Linea = "1";
var DTv = "1";

function switchProbabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv) {

  Internet = parseInt(Internet);
  Tv = parseInt(Tv);
  Linea = parseInt(Linea);
  // DTv = parseInt(DirecTV);  // DirecTV no existe
  DTv = parseInt(DTv);

  switch (true) {
    case Linea && Tv && Internet == 1: return 1
    case Linea && Tv && Internet && DTv == 1: return 2 // nunca llegará aquí
    case Linea && Tv && Internet == 1: return 3 // nunca llegará aquí, es un caso repetido
    case Linea && Tv && DTv == 1: return 4
    case Linea && Internet == 1: return 5
    case Linea && Internet && DTv == 1: return 6 // nunca llega aquí tampoco
    case Tv && Internet == 1: return 7
    case Tv && Internet && DTv == 1: return 8 // ni aquí
    case Linea == 1: return 9
    case Linea && DTv == 1: return 10 // ni aquí
    case Tv == 1: return 11
    case Tv && DTv == 1: return 12 // ni aquí
    case Internet == 1: return 13
    case Internet && DTv == 1: return 14  // ni aquí
    case DTv == 1: return 15
    default: return 0
  }
}
console.log(switchProbabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv))
```

Fíjate en los comentarios que he puesto y en los casos que nunca se cumpliran por que lo ordenas incorrectamente. Primero debes poner los casos que tengan más elementos involucrados.

Así sería mejor, pues todos los casos son alcanzables (excepto el 3 que está repetido):

```js
var Internet = "1"
var Tv = "1"
var Linea = "1"
var DTv = "1"

function switchProbabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv) {

  Internet = parseInt(Internet);
  Tv = parseInt(Tv);
  Linea = parseInt(Linea);
  // DTv = parseInt(DirecTV);  // DirecTV no existe
  DTv = parseInt(DTv);

  switch (true) {
    case Linea && Tv && Internet && DTv == 1: return 2 
    case Linea && Tv && Internet == 1: return 1
    case Linea && Tv && Internet == 1: return 3 // nunca llegará aquí, es un caso repetido
    case Linea && Tv && DTv == 1: return 4
    case Linea && Internet && DTv == 1: return 6 
    case Linea && Internet == 1: return 5
    case Tv && Internet && DTv == 1: return 8 
    case Tv && Internet == 1: return 7
    case Linea && DTv == 1: return 10 
    case Linea == 1: return 9
    case Tv && DTv == 1: return 12 
    case Tv == 1: return 11
    case Internet && DTv == 1: return 14  
    case Internet == 1: return 13
    case DTv == 1: return 15
    default: return 0
  }
}

console.log(switchProbabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv))
```

Me he tomado dos licencias no demasiado ortodoxas: 1) No usar el `break` porque el `return` impediría que llegara a el y 2) He puesto cada caso en una línea para acortar líneas y que se vea más compacto.

Comment: Excelente!!! que grande :D muchas gracias por tú ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Aunque ya tienes 3 respuestas, pienso que lo que podrías hacer es crear simplemente una cadena con los valores de cada variable y analizarla como un valor en binario.

Como cada parámetro toma el valor de un `bit`, pues se trata simplemente de convertir su representación binaria de conjunto (4 bits) en un valor decimal, que es lo que tratas de devolver en tu función.

Con 4 bits puedes representar valores decimales del 0 al 15, y ese es precisamente el resultado esperado de tu función. Para convertir una cadena que representa un valor binario en un decimal puedes usar el método [`parseInt(cadena, 2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), que recibe una cadena y la base numérica que la misma representa. Este método te devolverá el valor en base decimal de la cadena recibida.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function probabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv) {
  return parseInt(Array.from(arguments).join(''), 2);
}

let Internet = "1";
let Tv = "1";
let Linea = "1";
let DTv = "1";

console.log(probabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv)); // 15

Internet = "1";
Tv = "0";
Linea = "0";
DTv = "1";

console.log(probabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv)); // 9

Internet = "0";
Tv = "0";
Linea = "0";
DTv = "1";

console.log(probabilidades(Internet, Tv, Linea, DTv)); // 1
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100;
  top: 0;
}
```

Debes tomar en cuenta el orden en que se pasan los argumentos, ya que de esto depende el resultado obtenido.

Analizando la condición que has asociado a los valores que puedes devolver, se aprecia claramente que no hay una relación directa entre el valor devuelto y su representación binaria. Tal vez debas plantearte exactamente las prioridades o los casos de uso de dichos valores, así como su posición dentro de la cadena de bits. Estas reglas de negocio sólo tú las conoces. Pero tomando en cuenta el nombre de la función, estás tratando de ponderar del 0 al 15 la asignación de valor a los argumentos recibidos.

En cuanto a tu formulación, la forma de escribir este condicional es incorrecta:

```js
if(Linea && Tv && Internet == 1){
    return 1
}
```

Si en esa condición quieres decir que *si Line, Tv e Internet son iguales a 1*, la condición realmente debería escribirse así:

```js
if(Linea === 1 && Tv === 1 && Internet === 1){
    return 1
}
```

Hay una gran diferencia entre ambas, ya que en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) existe el concepto de [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy)y [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) y se refiere a la forma en que los valores se interpretan en un contexto booleano.

En tu condición Linea y TV no necesariamente valen 1, por lo cual aunque tomen otro valor distinto de los que se consideran `falsy` entonces la condición se cumplirá.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Ufff waooo!!! excelente, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ah servido muchísimo te lo agradezco <3